# Disord.py double output on message.content.find

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making my own discord dice roller bot using [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and I am running into a little scuffle.

Summed up when I type `d20` (which is the command to roll a dice with 20 sides on it) I get 2 rolls instead of one. However, the interesting part of this is that when I roll any other dice of a lower number I get one roll as needed.

Example:

```py
User: d10
Bot: 12

User: d20
Bot: 3
Bot: 16
```

Here is the code in question:

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    d4possible_responses = ['1','2', '3', '4']
    d6possible_responses = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    d8possible_responses = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
    d10possible_responses = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
    d20possible_responses = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']

    if (message.guild.id == 464298877823221761) or (message.guild.id == 712143774935154689) or (message.guild.id == 540812622619082782):
        if message.content.find("d4") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(':game_die: `'+ random.choice(d4possible_responses)+'`')
        if message.content.find("d6") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(':game_die: `'+ random.choice(d6possible_responses)+'`')
        if message.content.find("d8") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(':game_die: `'+ random.choice(d8possible_responses)+'`')
        if message.content.find("d10") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(':game_die: `'+ random.choice(d10possible_responses)+'`')
        if message.content.find("d20") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(':game_die: `'+ random.choice(d20possible_responses)+'`')
```

This is the entire cog: https://hastebin.com/mahabuluta.py

Comment: You are not showing the entire code which is causing the issue or you have an older instance of the bot running. Refresh your token, try again. If issue persists show more code.

Comment: there is no more code show, all I can add is that this is in a cog with the basic cog setup.

Answer (score 1):

Im writing here as an answer bc of no 50 reputation for commenting. ^^ - It's just a proposed solution.

Like @Tin Nguyen said, maybe u did some other bot before which just had the d20 implemented. Now 2 instances of the bot are reacting to the "d20" command and you get double ouput.

---

I would recommend you to restart the pc because I can't find any issue in the code.

Comment: Additionally, I hope you're doing this for DnD purposes ;)

Comment: You bet I am ;)

Comment: problem still occurring?

Comment: yes this is the entire cog: https://hastebin.com/mahabuluta.py

Comment: I see no problem